# How can I access the link bandwidth, delay from a mininet topology?

Tags: delay, bandwidth, mininet, sdn, ryu

I am using the Ryu Controller to send the packets from source to destination. I want to check the delay and bandwidth of the links created. How can I access these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Either configure this in the topology when you are setting it up
2. Use Ping/Iperf to figure out what the delay/bw is respectively
3. Check the configured interface's parameters using TC to get access to this.

Answer (score 0):

This app gives all the things you want as output.

```
    from ryu.base import app_manager
from ryu.controller import ofp_event
from ryu.controller.handler import MAIN_DISPATCHER,DEAD_DISPATCHER,set_ev_cls
from ryu.ofproto import ofproto_v1_3
from operator import attrgetter
from ryu.lib.mac import haddr_to_bin
from ryu.lib.packet import packet
from ryu.lib import mac,hub
from ryu.topology import event,switches
import copy
from ryu.topology.api import get_switch,get_link
import time
from ryu.lib.packet import ethernet,ipv4,ipv6,arp,icmp,ether_types,in_proto

class Link_Stat(app_manager.RyuApp):
    OFP_VERSIONS=[ofproto_v1_3.OFP_VERSION]
    def __init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs):
        super(Link_Stat,self).__init__(*_args, **_kwargs)
        self.mac_to_port={}
        self.topo_raw_switches=[]
        self.topo_raw_links=[]
        self.datapaths={}
        self.Graph_delay=[]
        self.Graph_bw=[]
        self.Graph_plr=[]
        self.PortMap_topo=[]
        self.PortMap_send=[]
        self.PortMap_recv=[]
        self.controller_mac='dd:dd:dd:dd:dd:dd'
        self.controller_ip='1.1.1.1'
        self.monitor_thread=hub.spawn(self.monitor_link_delay)
        self.monitor_thread=hub.spawn(self.monitor_link_loss)
        self.monitor_thread=hub.spawn(self.monitor_link_bw)
    def show_delay(self):
        hub.sleep(1)
        try:
            print("*"*10,"delay matrix","*"*10)
            switches=get_switch(self,None)
            links=get_link(self,None)
            if len(switches) !=0 and len(links)!=0:
                for x in range(len(switches)):
                    for y in range(len(switches)):
                        print(self.Graph_delay[x][y]," ",end=" ")
                    print()

        except :
            pass
    def show_bw(self):
        hub.sleep(1)
        try:
            print("*"*10,"bw matrix","*"*10)
            switches=get_switch(self,None)
            links=get_link(self,None)
            if len(switches) !=0 and len(links)!=0:
                for x in range(len(switches)):
                    for y in range(len(switches)):
                        print(self.Graph_bw[x][y]," ",end=" ")
                    print()
        except:
            pass

    def show_PLR(self):
        try:
            print("*"*10,"packet loss matrix(loss)","*"*10)
            switches=get_switch(self,None)
            links=get_link(self,None)
            if len(switches) !=0 and len(links)!=0:
                for x in range(len(switches)):
                    for y in range(len(switches)):
                        print(self.Graph_plr[x][y]," ",end=" ")
                    print()
            '''print("*"*10,"packet loss matrix(send)","*"*10)
            switches=get_switch(self,None)
            links=get_link(self,None)
            if len(switches) !=0 and len(links)!=0:
                for x in range(len(switches)):
                    for y in range(len(switches)):
                        print(self.PortMap_send[x][y]," ",end=" ")
                    print()
            print("*"*10,"packet loss matrix(rec)","*"*10)
            switches=get_switch(self,None)
            links=get_link(self,None)
            if len(switches) !=0 and len(links)!=0:
                for x in range(len(switches)):
                    for y in range(len(switches)):
                        print(self.PortMap_recv[x][y]," ",end=" ")
                    print()'''
        except:
            pass
    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPacketIn,MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _packet_in_handler(self,ev):
        msg=ev.msg
        datapath=msg.datapath
        ofproto=datapath.ofproto
        pkt=packet.Packet(msg.data)
        eth=pkt.get_protocols(ethernet.ethernet)[0]
        if eth.ethertype==ether_types.ETH_TYPE_IP and eth.dst==self.controller_mac:
            icmp_packet=pkt.get_protocol(icmp.icmp)
            echo_payload=icmp_packet.data
            #print("data=",echo_payload.data)
            payload=str(echo_payload.data.decode())
            info=payload.split(';')
            switch=info[0]
            latency=(time.time()-float(info[1]))*1000
            #print("delay from %d to %d is=%f",switch,datapath.id,latency)
            #print(latency)
            self.Graph_delay[int(switch)-1][int(datapath.id)-1]=latency
    def monitor_link_loss(self):
        while True:
            hub.sleep(2)
            try:
                links_list=get_link(self,None)
                mylinks=[(link.src.dpid,link.dst.dpid,link.src.port_no,link.dst.port_no) for link in links_list]
                self.topo_raw_switches=get_switch(self,None)
                if len(self.topo_raw_switches)>0:
                    self.PortMap_topo=[[0 for x in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))] for y in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))]
                    self.PortMap_send=[[0 for x in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))] for y in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))]
                    self.PortMap_recv=[[0 for x in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))] for y in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))]
                    self.Graph_plr=[[0 for x in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))] for y in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))]
                    for s1,s2,port1,port2 in mylinks:
                        self.PortMap_topo[int(s1)-1][int(s2)-1]=port1
                        self.PortMap_topo[int(s2)-1][int(s1)-1]=port2
                        self.PortMap_send[int(s1)-1][int(s2)-1]=0
                        self.PortMap_send[int(s2)-1][int(s1)-1]=0
                        self.PortMap_recv[int(s1)-1][int(s2)-1]=0
                        self.PortMap_recv[int(s2)-1][int(s1)-1]=0
                        self.Graph_plr[int(s1)-1][int(s2)-1]=0
                        self.Graph_plr[int(s2)-1][int(s1)-1]=0
                for dp in self.datapaths.values():
                    self._request_stats(dp)
            except Exception as inst:
                print("Exception=",inst)
            hub.sleep(3)
            self.calc_plr()
            self.show_PLR()
    def monitor_link_bw(self):
        while True:
            hub.sleep(2)
            try:
                links_list=get_link(self,None)
                mylinks=[(link.src.dpid,link.dst.dpid,link.src.port_no,link.dst.port_no) for link in links_list]
                self.topo_raw_switches=get_switch(self,None)
                if len(self.topo_raw_switches)>0:
                    self.Graph_bw=[[0 for x in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))] for y in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))]
                    for s1,s2,port1,port2 in mylinks:
                        self.Graph_bw[int(s1)-1][int(s2)-1]=0
                        self.Graph_bw[int(s1)-1][int(s2)-1]=0
                for dp in self.datapaths.values():
                    self._request_desc_stats(dp)
            except Exception as inst:
                print("Exception=",inst)
            hub.sleep(2)
            self.show_bw()
    def calc_plr(self):
        switches=get_switch(self,None)
        links=get_link(self,None)
        if len(switches)!=0 and len(links)!=0:
            for x in range(len(self.PortMap_send)):
                for y in range(len(self.PortMap_send)):
                    if self.PortMap_send[x][y]!=0:
                        self.Graph_plr[x][y]=(self.PortMap_send[x][y]-self.PortMap_recv[y][x])/self.PortMap_send[x][y]
                    else:
                        self.Graph_plr[x][y]=0
    def _request_stats(self,datapath):
        #self.logger.debug('send stats request: %016x',datapath.id)
        ofproto=datapath.ofproto
        parser=datapath.ofproto_parser
        req=parser.OFPPortStatsRequest(datapath,0,ofproto.OFPP_ANY)
        datapath.send_msg(req)
    def _request_desc_stats(self,datapath):
        self.logger.debug('send stats request: %016x',datapath.id)
        ofproto=datapath.ofproto
        parser=datapath.ofproto_parser
        # Request port/link descriptions, useful for obtainig bandwidth
        req=parser.OFPPortDescStatsRequest(datapath)
        datapath.send_msg(req)
    def monitor_link_delay(self):
        while True:
            hub.sleep(1)
            try:
                links_list=get_link(self,None)
                mylinks=[(link.src.dpid,link.dst.dpid,link.src.port_no,link.dst.port_no) for link in links_list]
                self.topo_raw_switches=get_switch(self,None)
                if len(self.topo_raw_switches)>0:
                    self.Graph_delay=[[0 for x in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))] for y in range(len(self.topo_raw_switches))]
                    for link in links_list:
                        self.Graph_delay[int(link.src.dpid)-1][int(link.dst.dpid)-1]=0
                    for s1,s2,port1,port2 in mylinks:
                        self.send_del_packet(int(s1),port1)
            except Exception as inst:
                print("Exception=",inst)
            self.show_delay()
    def send_del_packet(self,s_number,out_port):
        datapath= None
        if len(self.topo_raw_switches)>0:
            sws=get_switch(self,None)
            switches=[switch.dp for switch in sws]
            for s in switches:
                if int(s.id)==s_number:
                    datapath=s
        dpid=datapath.id
        pkt=packet.Packet()
        pkt.add_protocol(ethernet.ethernet(ethertype=ether_types.ETH_TYPE_IP,dst=self.controller_mac,src=self.controller_mac))
        pkt.add_protocol(ipv4.ipv4(proto=in_proto.IPPROTO_ICMP,src=self.controller_ip,dst=self.controller_ip))
        echo_payl='%d;%f' % (dpid,time.time())
        echo_payload=echo_payl.encode("utf-8")
        payload=icmp.echo(data=echo_payload)
        pkt.add_protocol(icmp.icmp(data=payload))
        pkt.serialize()
        actions=[datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPActionOutput(out_port)]
        out=datapath.ofproto_parser.OFPPacketOut(datapath=datapath,buffer_id=datapath.ofproto.OFP_NO_BUFFER,data=pkt.data,in_port=datapath.ofproto.OFPP_CONTROLLER,actions=actions)
        #self.logger.info("i am sending a packet %d and %d",s_number,out_port)
        datapath.send_msg(out)
    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPortStatus,MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _port_status_handler(self,ev):
        msg=ev.msg
        reason=msg.reason
        port_no=msg.desc.port_no
        ofproto=msg.datapath.ofproto
        if reason == ofproto.OFPPR_ADD:
            self.logger.info("port added %s",port_no)
        elif reason == ofproto.OFPPR_DELETE:
            self.logger.info("port Deleted %s",port_no)
        elif reason == ofproto.OFPPR_MODIFY:
            self.logger.info("port modified %s",port_no)
        else:
            self.logger.info("Illegal port state %s %s",port_no,reason)
    @set_ev_cls(event.EventSwitchEnter)
    def handler_switch_enter(self,ev):
        #the function get_switch(self,none) outpputs the list of switches.
        self.topo_raw_switches=copy.copy(get_switch(self,None))
        #the function get_link(self,none) outputs the list of links.
        self.topo_raw_links=copy.copy(get_link(self,None))
    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPortStatsReply,MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _port_stats_reply_handler(self,ev):
        body=ev.msg.body
        '''self.logger.info('datapath      port     '
                         'rx-pkts   rx-bytes    rx-error'
                         'tx-pkts   tx-bytes    tx-error')
        self.logger.info('-'*16,' ','--------'
                         '-------- --------- --------'
                         '-------- -------- --------')'''
        for stat in sorted(body,key=attrgetter('port_no')):
            '''self.logger.info('%016x %8x %8d %8d %8d %8d %8d %8d',
                             ev.msg.datapath.id,stat.port_no,stat.rx_packets,stat.rx_bytes,stat.rx_errors,
                             stat.tx_packets,stat.tx_bytes,stat.tx_errors)'''
            for x in range(len(self.PortMap_topo)):
                if int(stat.port_no)==self.PortMap_topo[int(ev.msg.datapath.id)-1][x]:
                    self.PortMap_send[int(ev.msg.datapath.id)-1][x]=stat.tx_packets
                    self.PortMap_recv[int(ev.msg.datapath.id)-1][x]=stat.rx_packets
    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPortDescStatsReply,MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def port_desc_stats_reply_handler(self,ev):
        '''for p in ev.msg.body:
            self.logger.info('port_no=%d hw_addr=%s name=%s config=0x%08x '
                             'state=0x%08x curr=0x%08x advertised=0x%08x '
                             'supported=0x%08x peer=0x%08x curr_speed=%d '
                             'max_speed=%d' %
                             (p.port_no, p.hw_addr,p.name,p.config,p.state,p.curr,p.advertised,p.supported,p.peer,p.curr_speed,p.max_speed))'''
        switch=ev.msg.datapath
        for x in range(len(self.PortMap_topo)):
            for p in ev.msg.body:
                if int(p.port_no)==self.PortMap_topo[int(switch.id)-1][x]:
                    self.Graph_bw[int(switch.id)-1][x]=p.curr_speed
    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPStateChange,[MAIN_DISPATCHER,DEAD_DISPATCHER])
    def _state_change_handler(self,ev):
        datapath=ev.datapath
        if ev.state == MAIN_DISPATCHER:
            if datapath.id not in self.datapaths:
                self.logger.debug('register datapath: %016x',datapath.id)
                self.datapaths[datapath.id]=datapath
        elif ev.state == DEAD_DISPATCHER:
            if datapath.id in self.datapaths:
                self.logger.debug('unregister datapath: %016x', datapath.id)
                del self.datapaths[datapath.id]
```